# How to center items inside ion-grid?

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I'm trying to center (both horiz and vertical) and stack the 2 social buttons but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left outline color="fb" (click)="fbClicked($event)">
  <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" color="#3B5998"></ion-icon>
  CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK
</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
     <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button icon-left outline>
  <ion-icon name="logo-google"></ion-icon>
  CONNECT WITH GOOGLE
</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully aware of all ionic built in classes but you can use flexbox for this case and android and ios has a good support of it. I changed your code a bit and simplified it.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  

});
```

```css
.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 
    
    <title>Ionic</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Social Buttons</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    
    
<ion-content  class="Aligner">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <div class = "col">
        <button color="fb" (click)="fbClicked($event)">
  <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" color="#3B5998"></ion-icon>
  CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK
</button>
      </div>

      <div class = "col">
        <button>
  <ion-icon name="logo-google"></ion-icon>
  CONNECT WITH GOOGLE
</button>
      </div>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
    

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I'm still looking for an ionic way to do this

Comment: It seems that the Ionic way is not working so great at the v4, so, thank you for the tip, it works.